# How can I install Django 1.1?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, virtualenv, django-1.1

I have a django project This was done some years before and used django 1.1 in it.

Now i want to do some modification in it. In order to do the maintenance i need to install Django 1.1 . And I want to use virtualenv to run this project.

But when I tried to install Django 1.1 using pip it shows the following message:

```
pip install django==1.1
Downloading/unpacking django==1.1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==1.1 (from versions: )
No distributions matching the version for django==1.1
```

Can anyone help me out from this problem?

Comment: I strongly advise AGAINST running older versions of django. Unless you have a large existing codebase that prevents migration -- it is best to go with the latest greatest. The Django folks materially improve the framework with each realease and there will definitely be bug fixes and features you will want in the latest.

Comment: The thing is that this project is already been done some years before and its done using django 1.1 .Now i need to do some modification in it . So i need to install django 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try capital 'D':

```
pip install Django==1.1.4
```

P.S. You can see the available versions on PyPI here: https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/

Comment: Ah, it appears they updated the index with more versions.

Comment: This(pip install Django==1.1) also giving me the same result. No distributions matching the version for Django==1.1.

Comment: @arocks So your saying that there is no Django version like django 1.1 . I only be possible to install Django 1.1.3 or 1.1.4. Thanks arocks i am accepting your answer.